# Does anyone know if it's possible to make an iMessage link preview like Twitter?

Tags: html, ios, facebook-opengraph

I have tried every combination of og:type, og:description, og:title as well as other tags and can not come up with a preview like twitter does on iMessage.  I'm thinking this preview may be hardcoded only for Twitter? The top image is what I want, the bottom image is all I can get.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered that Twitter is in fact hard coded into the link presentation framework in iOS.  You can see the strings found in the LinkPresentation framework.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which file is this in exactly?

Comment: The executable file for LinkPresentation.framework

Comment: Wow, great find. I had the exact same question but didn't think to dig this deep. Wish Apple would give other links this UI functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>

<meta name="twitter:image" content="Your Website Title"/>

<meta name="twitter:title" content="Your Website Link"/>

<meta name="twitter:description" content="Some description…."/>
```

Comment: Does not work, discovered apple has twitter hard coded in.